# how to convert the sql to QueryBuilder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-8

```
$old_records = DB::connection("mysql_old_s")->table('leads')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as  source_count, source'))
        ->groupBy('source')
        ->get();
dd($old_records); // works right
```

This query works right.
I want to add one more column like **id** or **created_at** to select

I couldn't do it as following:

```
$old_records = DB::connection("mysql_old_s")->table('leads')
        ->select('id',DB::raw('count(*) as source_count, source'))
        ->groupBy('source')
        ->get();
dd($old_records); // it gives an error
```

It gives me an error that is:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP 
BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'crmclini_crmv2.leads.id' which is not functionally 
dependent on columns in GROUP BY
clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `id`, count(*) as 
source_count, source , id from `leads` group by `source`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include the columns you select within your group by clause to group by them:

```
$old_records = DB::connection("mysql_old_s")->table('leads')
        ->select('id',DB::raw('count(*) as source_count, source'))
        ->groupBy(['id','source'])
        ->get();
```

the second option (witch I do not recommend), you can disable only_full_group_by option in config/database.php:

'connections' => [
...

```
'mysql' => [
...
    'strict' => false,
    ...

],
]
```

unless you have special condition, make the query group by the columns you select